# Linear Feedback Shift Register

Tags: python-3.x

I have taken this code taken from the questions posed by stackoverflow members:

```
def lfsr(seed, taps):
    sr, xor = seed, 0
    while 1:
        for t in taps:
            xor += int(sr[t-1])
        if xor%2 == 0.0:
            xor = 0
        else:
            xor = 1
        print xor
        sr, xor = str(xor) + sr[:-1], 0
        print sr
        if sr == seed:
            break

lfsr('11001001', (8,7,6,1))
```

I understand the code but I want to print only the first 10 results of this LFSR and ignore the others. How can  I do that in python 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the code again, but not sure it is exactly what you need for:

```
def lfsr(seed, taps):
    sr, xor = seed, 0
    for _ in range(10):
        for t in taps:
            xor += int(sr[t - 1])
        if xor % 2 == 0.0:
            xor = 0
        else:
            xor = 1
        # print(xor)
        sr, xor = str(xor) + sr[:-1], 0
        # print(sr)
        if sr == seed:
            break
    print("Return %s" % sr)
    return sr


truth_table = {
    '00000': '0',
    '00001': '1',
    '00010': '1',
    ...
    '11111': '0',

}

lfsr_r = []
lfsr_r.append(lfsr('11001001', (8, 7, 6, 1)))
lfsr_r.append(lfsr('11001001', (3, 4)))
lfsr_r.append(lfsr('11001001', (7, 8)))
lfsr_r.append(lfsr('11001001', (2, 3, 5)))
lfsr_r.append(lfsr('11001001', (1, 4, 7)))

for pos in range(10):
    seq = ''
    # get [pos] bit from each sequence
    for r in lfsr_r:
        seq += lfsr_r[r][pos]
    result = truth_table[seq]
    print("Result for %s column: %s" % (pos, result))
```

Comment: Assuming that I want only the last right bit in each of the 10 results and using pop() function enabled me to do so but having five LFSRs and for each of them I have printed the last right bit in each of the 10 results like this:                                                                                                               lfsr('11001001', (8,7,6,1)) = 1001001101

Comment: lfsr('11001001', (8,7,6,1)) =   1001001101                                                                    
   LFSRs('11001001', (3,4))  = 1001001101                                                                  
   LFSRs('11001001', (7,8)) =

Comment: 1001001110                                                                 
   I want now to check result with the others and give them a value accordingly. To be clearer:

Comment: 1001001101                                                                                           
   1001001101                                                                                           
   1001001110
   1001001100                                                                                           
   1001001110                                                                                            
   ---------------                                   
   110100101

Comment: So if the first number in each LFSR = 1 , I give 1, and if all of them 0 give 1 and so on. This will be done for all the 10 numbers.

Comment: How can I achieve this

Comment: I did not get you completely.. You are trying to make a function on a result of previous one, right? So input values will be the list of given strings, right?

Could you give an example what should be done as a result of the given strings transformation?

Comment: Sure. Let's say LFSR1 = 1001001101, LFSR2 = 1001001101, LFSR3 =  1001001110, LFSR4 = 1001001100 & LFSR5= 1001001110. I have a truth table which says 00000 = 0, 00001 = 1 and so on. Right now, I need to see the result of each LFSR. So the first number in LFSR1 =1, LFSR2=1,LFSR3=1 and the same for LFSR4&LFSR5. So I check the table which says 11111 = 0. I need to do that for each number.

Comment: I have added some code in the answer, maybe it is what you need.

Comment: I tried your code but it gives me this error:   lfsr_r += lfsr('11001001', (8, 7, 6, 1))[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. This approach will add all the characters or only just first. Because I intend to add all the characters.

Comment: Ok, let's clarify this one more time.. What should return `lfsr()` function with one call? Just one sequence of 10 char-string, right?
I thought you have modified `lfsr()` function to return needed value. It seems it only prints and returns None. What variable should it return there? `sr` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the lfsr() returns the results for each register after returning the result I need to do what I described above. To be clearer:                                                                                                          LFSR1 = 1001001101 LFSR2 = 1001001101  LFSR3 = 1001001110  LFSR4 = 100100110 LFSR5= 1001001110. I am getting the results of LFSR1,2,3,4 & 5. Now I need to add them according to the truth table.

Comment: Not exactly what I want to achive. after I have poped the last right bit for all the 10 in lfsr('11001001', (8, 7, 6, 1)) , I got  LFSR1 = 1001001101. The same process I did for the rest. However, after I getting the retuened results for all the lfsrs from lfsr(), I need to add the result of each register to the other. For eaxmple, 1001001101 + 1001001101 + 1001001110 + 100100110 + 1001001110 = 1111100000. I made up the final result but when I add the first char [1,1,1,1,1] I need to check the value in the truth table and return it until I add the all 10 in all registers.

Comment: Sorry for me being so stupid :) So you're adding 5 10-bit sequences by one digit.. And when you're adding [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] - would you like to firstly sum these digits (and get 101 - binary 5) and then check the truth table by 101? OR first check the truth table by '11111' and get, well, '1' and do the same with remaining digits?

Comment: I want first to check from the truth table and then assign a value. For adding the 5 10bit sequences I am not clear at what you ment. So I'll explain it to make sure we're in the same page. LFSR1 + LFSR2 + LFSR3 +LFSR4 + LFSR5 = 1001001101 + 1001001101 + 1001001110 + 100100110 + 1001001110 = 1111100000. So I'll adding bit by bit for all the five. So first bit 1+1+1+1+1, I go to the truth table and check 1,1,1,1 what value to assign. The second bits, 0+0+0+0+0,  I go to the truth table and check 0,0,0,0,0 what value to assign until I finish all the 10. I hope the picture now is clearer.

Comment: Yes, got it.. But look, adding these 5 numbers we get 101001011100 which is 12-digits long instead of 10. Should we ignore carrying?

Comment: It will 10 only. We're not adding, I can say just comparing the values. So that     LFSR1= 1001001101
    LFSR2= 1001001101
    LFSR3= 1001001110  
    LFSR4= 100100110
    LFSR5= 1001001110 
    Result=  1111100000. How I did the result I compare the bit in each LFSRs and assign the exact value in the truth table. So 1 1 1 1 1 is 1 because in the truth table '1,1,1,1,1' = '1'. The same for the others.

Comment: I give up.. I don't understand what should be added to what.. By the way the function returns 8-char strings instead of 10-char.
I'd recommend you to summarize everything and ask another question. Maybe someone helps you again.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to give you more control over how the values computed by the function are used is to turn the function into a generator. Just replace the `print sr` line with `yield sr` instead (and remove the `print xor` earlier):

```
def lfsr(seed, taps):
    sr, xor = seed, 0
    while 1:
        for t in taps:
            xor += int(sr[t-1])
        if xor%2 == 0.0:
            xor = 0
        else:
            xor = 1
        sr, xor = str(xor) + sr[:-1], 0
        yield sr
        if sr == seed:
            break
```

The way you call the function will need to change, since it doesn't do any printing itself any more. To replicate the old behavior, use a `for` loop like this:

```
for state in lfsr('11001001', (8,7,6,1)):
    print state[0] # the xor value
    print state # the sr value
```

To limit the output to 10 values, you can modify that loop using `enumerate` and do a `break` when you see the index 10 (the 11th result):

```
for i, state in enumerate(lfsr('11001001', (8,7,6,1))):
    if i == 10:
        break
    # printing or whatever here
```

There are probably other approaches to limiting the number of results (such as using `itertools.islice`) that would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using pylfsr, you could get the expected results. For your example of 8-bit LFSR and feedback polynomial [8,7,6,1] (lfsr('11001001', (8,7,6,1)), here is  the code to get first 10 bits of output

```
import numpy as np
from pylfsr import LFSR

s = '11001001'
s = [int(b) for  b in s]
L = LFSR(initstate=s, fpoly=[8,7,6,1])
seq = L.runKCycle(10)
print(seq)
```

output

```
[1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1]
```